# Where is the output of ProGuard's -whyareyoukeeping in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I am using ProGuard in the gradle settings of my app in Android Studio. In the "Gradle Console" window I am able to read warnings from proGuard. However, when I use the `whyareyoukeeping`, nothing is diplayed there. Am I missing something?

Here's an example of the way I tried to use it:

```
-whyareyoukeeping class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzel
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured that if I add the "--info" flag in the command-line options of Gradle, then all the output of ProGuard is displayed in Gradle console.

[image: Android Studio -> Project Settings]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record:

For example, add the following option:

`-whyareyoukeeping class **.MyApplication`

Then open the Gradle Console tab (down on the right) and run "Build" > "Build SDK". During the building, you'll see (or will be able to look for them later) lines like these printed:

```
Shrinking...
Explaining why classes and class members are being kept...

your.package.name.MyApplication
  is kept by a directive in the configuration.
```

If you don't find these lines, maybe you should add `--info`, to Gradle Console command-line options, as Petrakeas specified, restart Android Studio and try again.

Comment: Nice that it doesn´t print which directive was the reason. Really easy to find the cause within hundrets of lines of proguard conf

Answer (score 0):

You have to check "generic" in the filters of the Messages panel.

[image]